# Remap the editor keys so that words with underscores between them behave like dashes/spaces when using Alt + ←/→ keys to jump between them?

Tags: keyboard, spaces

**Background:**

When we encounter words like `color-black` (with a hyphen) or `color_black` (with an underscore), or even `color black` (with a space), we know we can navigate between words or hyphenated words by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ← or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + → keys to jump between words.

However, if the words are separated by an underscore, then we do not get the benefit of jumping between words, as the '_' is treated more like a letter instead of a separator?

**Question:**

Is it possible to modify the system so that when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ←, it treats the `_` as a space or a dash and then jumps between the words?

**Reason Why**:

The reason for this is that some developers prefer to use `_` inside HTML class and id names because they can jump to the beginning of an entire id or class easier, while others prefer dashes because of the aesthetic appearance, ease of typing (no need to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>), or just because they prefer the ability to jump between the hyphenated words.

If we can make one behave how the other behaves, it's easier to agree on a common standard naming convention.

Comment: Personally, I like camel case. i.e. camelCase.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case Thus, avoiding the whole issue. It's a lot easier to hold down the shift and type a letter than trying to press the - or _.

Comment: That being said, what editor are you using? You could try hacking a solution.  Try keyboard maestro.  Intercept the keystroke and direct to a macro to figure out where to move the cursor. Good luck with performance.